# Multiplied breakpoints in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

Sometimes when I debugging code I see in "Breakpoints" window my breapoints which are multipied. I use Visual Studio 2013.

Does anyone know what they mean and when they are created?

[image]

Comment: Any threading involved?

Comment: It is MVC application, I use single thread.

Comment: A bad .suo file maybe. Breakpoints are stored in the corresponding .suo-file of a solution. Delete this file and see if it is fixed. Be aware that the .suo-file also stores other information

Comment: Peter, I do not believe this is the same issue as the linked duplicate. Based on the screenshot, I would guess that your app is creating multiple AppDomains. As each AppDomain creates a duplicate of your code, each breakpoint in that code will also be duplicated (though to a different address in the app's memory). You can confirm this by right-clicking on a breakpoint and selecting Go To Disassembly (noting the address). Repeat for another of the duplicated breakpoints and compare addresses.